# NodeJs - Return a dot function from within a function

Tags: node.js

So the basic idea is I am working on converting some java code to run in NodeJS. I have a call GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment that returns a String. For testing, I've tried:

```
function GraphicsEnvironment()
{
  function getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(value)
  {
    alert(value);
    return getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(value);
  };
};
```

But this still returns:

```
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment is not a function.
```

What is the simplest way to do this so the code can remain in a single file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this as an Object so that you can retrieve the function needed

```
const GraphicsEnvironment = {
getLocalGraphicsEnvironment: function (value)
  {
    alert(value);
    return this.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought I had this, but what if I have multiple functions within GraphicsEnvironment. Ex. getCurrentMontior().

Comment: I got it. I was missing a comma in between sub functions.